# An efficient way of finding pairs of sets in a set of sets

Tags: python, set

I have a set of sets : {1,2,3...}, and I want to find all pairs (, ) such that ∩≠∅.

The only way I could come up with was repeating condition check Σ time.

If I can represent this with a python-ish pseudo code:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

setA = {A1, A2, A3, A4....}
setACopy = deepcopy(setA)

intersectingPairs = set()

for Ai in setA:
    for Aj in setACopy:
        if isIntersect(Ai, Aj):
            intersectingPairs.add((Ai, Aj))
    setACopy.remove(Ai)
```

I expect this to be very time consuming as the size of `setA` increases.

Is there a better algorithm that I can refer to?

Comment: Come to think about it, I should not execute `setACopy.remove(Ai)` in the for loop....

Comment: This might be something you can address using graph theory. I need to think about it a sec. My first thought was "finding connected components" but I'm not sure that's the exact same problem.

Comment: Also, set of sets is a bit of a problem in python, since a default set is not hashable. Can you elaborate on that, or provide a simple implementation?

Comment: @KennyOstrom The less general version of my question is that I want to use this algorithm with `shapely` library so that I can report something like polygon A is intersecting with polygon B.  I think the object type does not necessarily need to be a `set` of `set`s. Basically anything that I can do basic set operations(finding union, intersection.... etc) will work.

Comment: For the record, the fastest way to implement `isIntersect` would be as `if not Ai.isdisjoint(Aj):`; a lot of folks try writing it as `if Ai & Aj:` which is much slower when intersections occur in larger `set`s (because it can't short-circuit and has to build an unnecessary temporary `set`; it has to find *all* the intersecting elements and put them in a new `set`, when you only care if there is at least one). Using `not` to flip the result of `isdisjoint` is *much* faster, producing no temporary `set`s and short-circuiting. Not a big-O improvement, but important in practice.

Comment: If these are shapes that treat "touching" as a set intersection operation, then my lookup table may not help. You'd need to treat every point as a separate element to find all the intersections, and that could grow the data size way faster than just treating each shape as a graph node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than checking each pair individually, you can linearly parse the data to build a lookup table. If the connections are sparse, this can pretty quickly yield the unique pairs you wanted.

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

A1 = {1, 2, 3}
A2 = {2, 4, 6}
A3 = {1, 3, 5}
A4 = {2, 3, 5}
A5 = {8, 9}

# Change them to tuples so they are hashable
superset = set((tuple(subset) for subset in [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5]))

# build families of all sets with a specific element
lookup = defaultdict(list)
for subset in superset:
    for element in subset:
        lookup[element].append(subset)

# If the families are small, brute force from there
pairs = set()
for __, family in lookup.items():
    for result in combinations(family, 2):
        pairs.add(result)

pprint (pairs)
```

If the connections are not sparse, this might even be worse than looking at every pair. But if they are sparse, it can be really fast.

Comment: Note: `tuple` works fine here, but might be a pain if you need set behaviors later. If you want to keep them set-like, you can just convert to `frozenset` instead (which is *exactly* the same as `set` aside from `frozenset` being immutable/hashable). Also, `set((tuple(subset) for subset in [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5]))` is a kind of bloated way to spell (using `set` constructor plus generator expression) the faster equivalent set comprehension `{tuple(subset) for subset in [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5]}`.

Comment: Good point. I just wanted to be explicit, to make it easier for OP to convert to the actual set-like class they are using from some specific library.